# What is the formal name of the number-picking game?

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

You know that game, where you and an opponent take turns choosing numbers, and the last person to take their turn before the cumulative total passes a preset value, is the winner? What's the formal name of that game? I know it's a solved game in that there's an algorithm to generate the winning moves, but, given that google doesn't understand "that game where people take turns picking numbers", it's hard to search.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a simple (one heap) version of [Nim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim). Probably has its own name, but doesn't need its own analysis...

[Edit: although, isn't this game silly? If the preset total is 12, then clearly player 1 is going to say "11", and that's game over?]

Comment: The reason this is non-trivial is because for our application the numbers you can pick are restricted to powers of six. So, among other things, we're hitting problems of scale.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [impartial game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impartial_game).